# Trouble with Autobench and setting httperf_add-header

Tags: cookies, load-testing, httperf, autobench

I want to load test my application and need a Cookie for it.
I've looked all of the other questions and have tried this:

In **autobench.conf**

httperf_add-header = "Cookie: cookie_name=cookie_string\n"

Still not working. I believed is ignored.

But, when I run httperf like:

> httperf --add-header="Cookie: cookie_name=cookie_string\n" --server=server --port=port--uri=/uri

It works perfect.

So, how do i make it work for Autobench?

Thanks in advance.